# Edges in object mode arent connected, but they are in edit mode

Tags: objects, edit-mode, object-mode

In edit mode, these edges are connected, but in object mode, these edges are seperated. These were 2 different objects and i joined them. I want them to be connected and i dont know how to get it like that in object mode.

[image: connected]
[image: not connected]

edit: these are not very clear, heres some more screenshots: [image: object mode, not connected] [image: edit mode, connected]

The newer screenshots were taken in the exact same place, all i did was switch the mode and it connected the parts where there were holes. i want to figure out how to apply the auto connecting that its doing in edit mode and apply that to object mode.

Comment: Hello and welcome. It is unclear what you are asking. Please use the [edit] link at the 
bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add 
more information on how you set up your project.
[Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that 
might help us understand your scene and settings. See [How to upload 
an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491).

Comment: Hello please share your object

Comment: could you please share your .blend file: https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: sadly i cannot share my blend file because it contains a model rip from a paid video game

Comment: Maybe there is a modifier that causes the holes? Did you use *Merge by Distance* after you joined the objects?

Comment: If you still have 2 objects on the outliner, then, the parts are not joined

Comment: there is only 1 modifier, (decimate), which just shown me that there was indeed a hole between the objects that i joined
i just want to apply what edit mode does automatically (connecting the edges and vertices if there is a hole) to object mode.

Comment: In the _Edit Mode_ screenshot it looks a lot like the edges where the holes appear in _Object Mode_ are darker/thicker, which indicates that there are duplicate edges lying in the same places. I guess if you click on one to select it and move it, you can see that there is another one remaing in place (as long you haven't got _Proportional Editing_ turned on). So I suspect the answer given by @YousufChaudhry is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The *Edit Mode* **doesn't** do anything automatically. It's just that the `decimate modifier` ***isn't* visible** in *Edit Mode*.

To solve this, select all of your mesh by pressing `A`, and then press `M` > `Merge By Distance`. The problem will be solved. If you want this to happen automatically, just enable this button in the top bar in *Edit Mode*:

[image: auto merge]

Some important things to note: *Auto Merge* only works with vertex transformations, i.e. translation (moving), rotation and scaling. This means, if you are not moving, rotating or scaling vertices to bring them close together, they will not be automatically merged no matter how close they are. For example, joining two objects with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> will not merge vertices on the new joined object until you move at least one of them in *Edit Mode*. Also a *Mirror* modifier will not *Auto Merge* vertices after applying if you have the *Merge* option disabled in the modifier. And it works only with executed transformations, so if you start to move, rotate or scale vertices and abort the transformation by right-clicking or hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd>, *Auto Merge* will not merge close vertices.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thanks for the tip! I'll edit it (or you could if you want to)

Comment: Wasn't on my computer until now, but I edited it in :)